# Linearly Dependent/Independent, how to provide proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Prove that a vector $V$ and a vector $cV$ are linearly independent or dependent.

It's clear that the vectors are a Linear Combination of each other, and span a line, but how do I prove formally that they are dependent?

Comment: If there exist $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = 0$ then $v_1,v_2$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: They are dependent cause $(-c)V+cV$ equals to zero vector.